# Why are all pups born at the same time?

Tags: dogs

I live in India, alongside 30 Million stray dogs.  90% of female dogs have given birth to pups in November-December. You can see a pup every 10 m you walk here. Why is this happening? Why do all dogs are having pups at the same time?

Edit: I read on the net and found that Indian stray dog, named pariah goes into heat once a year during mating season August - Jan. Their gestation period is 2 months so November- December is when most pups are born. But why do pariahs, unlike most others go into heat once and all at the same time?

You can read about their mating season in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_pariah_dog) or any other site. I could not find the explanation.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about concluding all pups born at the same time from your limited observation.

Comment: I live in India too. Dogs go into heat twice a year. I don't think that your assumption is right.

Comment: @Sonevol but Sir I can see pups nowadays everywhere. When I go to my school, 4 km away I can literally see atleast 20-30 puppies near the roads. All the females in the pack(3) of my locality had pups as well.

Comment: May be true but I can see pups here all year round, not specifically in winter season.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware canine breeding cycles aren't governed explictly by time of year, however as we are talking about strays here presumably there are times of year where the environmental conditions (weather, availability of food etc) are significantly more conducive to newborn pups surviving and wuithout wanting to sound morbid there will be times when the opposite is true - and in those conditions the newborns will probably die quite quickly, so they won't be around long enough for you to see them.

This affect will be further compounded by the ones born during good conditions - Since more of these pups survive (and they will all reach reproducitive maturity at approximately the same time) they will probably start breeding around the the same sort of time and over enough generations you'll start to get these synchronizing up resulting in the sorts of spikes in the puppy population that you're seeing.

Comment: But sir cold isn't a good weather to survive in. I might not have noticed it before, but now you cannot truly spot a female that doesn't have pups now. What I estimated as well is that out of 100 million (or even more) pups born in a year in India, only 1-2 million live, rest all are killed.

Comment: That blows my theory out of the water then! I'd failed to realize that it's winter in India now too.. I blame the lack of caffeine!

Comment: Most Indian states have an average temperature of or over 14-15 degrees Celsius in November-December. Dogs can easily survive in that kind of weather.